# Play youtube video on iPhone by not pressing the default video icon

Tags: iphone, youtube, mpmovieplayer

i want to know if it is possible to launch the youtube video without launching the default small photo icon. I just need a regular icon which is able to be launched to play a youtube video. Unfortunately, as the Youtube official suggestion suggests, there is currently no way to fulfill my request.  Does any body concern this issue and already figure this out?

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html

Comment: Way off topic for this site as it is not a question related to programming. [Superuser](http://www.superuser.com) would be a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly:

1. embed youtube player in a UIWebview and set the webview to hidden
2. in your customized button method do the following:

   a- search for UIButton in the webview subviews :

`-(UIButton*)getButtonInView:(UIView*)view{`

```
UIButton *button = nil;
     if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
      return (UIButton*) view;
     }

 if(view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
  for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
   button=[self getButtonInView:subview];
   if(button) return button;
  }
 }

 return button;
```

`}`

b- send action to the fetched button:

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

hope that will help

**----NOTE----**

As mentioned by lxt. Please note that that this solution relies on Youtube plugin implementation not changing otherwise it might break in the future.

Comment: Worth knowing that this solution relies on undocumented classes that Apple could change, so may not be suitable for a production environment (your risk is Apple updates iOS which then breaks that feature of the app).

Comment: thats completely true and I agree with your point. it depends on the implementation of the youtube plugin is not changing.. I will edit my answer.